# Compiler options selective application

Tags: c++, compiler-options

can compiler options be applied selectively on my files?
I want some files to be covered by some option but not the other files.

Comment: How are you compiling your files? Do you use a makefile, or a specific IDE? Which options do you want to set selectively? Which compiler/linker are you using?

Comment: I think it's funny that you don't even care to mention what tools you are using. We are forced to tell you "Yes you can". because, in the end, you can write your own compiler that supports it if you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that you might be using Make files:

This should get you started: Note how -fopenmp gets added just for source2.c

```
CC=gcc
SRC=source1.c source2.c
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
EXE=source1.exe
FLAGS= -g -O2

source2.o: FLAGS+=-fopenmp

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)

clean:
    rm $(EXE)$
```

Output of make -Bsn:

```
gcc -o source1.o source1.c -g -O2
gcc -o source2.o source2.c -g -O2 -fopenmp
gcc -o source1 source1.o source2.o -g -O2
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  You invoke the compiler, and you can tell it what you want.

Some tools may add some restrictions; Visual Studio, as far as I know, only allows specifying options at the project level.  But that's an artificial restriction of the tool (and I'm sure there are ways around it—I just don't know them).

Comment: Visual Studio (at least from 2005 until 2010 versions) allows you to select compiler options separately for each file in the project...